# Access denied when trying to access server with PuTTY "invalid user" "failed password"

Tags: server, openssh

I installed open-ssh.

Trying to access the server with PuTTY gives me `access denied`.
Logs of the server show `Invalid user` and `failed password`.

`PermitRootLogin` is already changed to `yes`.

Which configuration (presumably in `sshd_config`) has to be changed?

Comment: The Root user doesn't have a password by default.  Did you set one?  Did you restart your SSH process after adjusting the config?  Are you trying to SSH as root or your own user?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server. I tried my login with a standard account.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you on?  Is your system set "PasswordAuthentication yes" in sshd_config?

Comment: (And i set a root password. Same as my admin user password.) But even the login as standard user is not possible. The server receives the requests and says, that the user is "invalid". I don't understand why.

Comment: It's 18.04.01. Yes, "#PasswordAuthentication" is set to yes.

Comment: Remove # in front of `PasswordAuthentication yes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out to solve the problem.

The account name had to be written in lower case.